# Pandas pivot table value counts

Tags: pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I have a dataframe in format:

```
 Name     Score    Bin
 John     90       80-100
 Marc     30       20-40
 John     10       0-20
 David    20       0-20
```

...

I want to create a pivot table that looks like this:

```
Name    0-20    20-40    40-60    60-80    80-100   Total count   Avg score
John     1       2        nan      nan      2            5         60.53
Marc    nan      2        nan      nan     nan           2         32.13
David   3        2        nan      nan     nan           5         21.80
```

So I want to have columns that show count of values for each bucket, as well as total count of values and average score.

I have tried

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Score', "Bin"], index=["nAME"],
                   aggfunc={"Score" : np.average, "Bin" : "count"},
                    dropna=True, margins = True)
```

however I just get overall count and not broken down per bucket

Comment: `df.groupby('Name')['Bin'].value_counts().unstack('Bin')`

Answer (score 0):

Do your task in 3 steps:

1. Generate a pivot_table:

   ```
   df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Name', columns='Bin', values='Score', aggfunc='count')\
       .reindex(columns=['0-20', '20-40', '40-60', '60-80', '80-100'])\
       .rename_axis(columns='')
   ```

   The result, for your source data extended to give roughly your expected
   result, is:

   ```
          0-20  20-40  40-60  60-80  80-100
   Name                                    
   David   3.0    2.0    NaN    NaN     NaN
   John    1.0    2.0    NaN    NaN     2.0
   Marc    NaN    2.0    NaN    NaN     NaN
   ```

   Note: As *NaN* is a special case of *float*, other values are also of
   *float* type.
2. Generate *Total_count* and *Avg_score*:

   ```
   df3 = df.groupby('Name')\
       .agg(Total_count=('Score', 'count'), Avg_score=('Score', 'mean'))\
       .rename(columns={'Total_count': 'Total count', 'Avg_score': 'Avg score'})
   ```

   The result is:

   ```
          Total count  Avg score
   Name                         
   David            5       21.8
   John             5       61.0
   Marc             2       32.0
   ```
3. Join both above tables:

   ```
   result = df2.join(df3)
   ```

   The result is:

   ```
          0-20  20-40  40-60  60-80  80-100  Total count  Avg score
   Name                                                            
   David   3.0    2.0    NaN    NaN     NaN            5       21.8
   John    1.0    2.0    NaN    NaN     2.0            5       61.0
   Marc    NaN    2.0    NaN    NaN     NaN            2       32.0
   ```